# Is the shape of (SMD) pads relevant?

Tags: surface-mount, pad

SMD pads come in basically two shapes: rectangular and rounded rectangle. Does either offer advantages? For instance for etching, or HF signal integrity?

Comment: previously: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7011

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the most part, no.  It doesn't matter.  Or, to put it a different way:  For about 95% of the designs out there, the shape of the pad does not matter.  There are some things to consider, however, before just assuming that your pads are correct:

- BGA's need round pads of a very specific size.
- The pad has to be big enough to hold enough solder paste to do the job.  There needs to be enough solder to create a proper fillet for reliable soldering.  The size of the stencil, along with the size of the pad, will determine how much solder is available for that pin.
- Some RF guy is going to say that the shape matters.  I am not an RF guy.  But I do design digital circuits with 2.5+ GHz signals and the pads don't matter for me.
- Sometimes the shape of the pad is used to identify Pin 1.  Square pad for pin 1, rounded pad for the other pins.
- One might argue that pads with rounded corners are less likely to de-laminate.  I have no idea if this is true or not.  But if it is true, it can only make a difference if there is a lot of rework being done on the PCB.  For normal automated assembly of PCB's, this doesn't seem to matter.
- If the part manufacturer recommends a specific pad size/shape, then you better follow what they say.
- Square pads will get slightly rounded off in the etching process.  For medium to large pads you'll never notice.  For small pads you might care.  I almost never care.